# Doctrine 2 Tutorials or books?

Tags: doctrine

I'm trying to find any tutorials or books to get started with Doctrine 2, but seems there are not many resources especially for 2. If you know any tutorials or books please let me know. Thanks

Comment: I disagree, the official documentation is good enough to get started and more.

Answer (score 1):

actually, the documentation is good if you are using it the way they are using it.  But if you are using other objects, you will have a hard time finding documentation for it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [official documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/) is really good, and there is no need for any other resources... There is a series of articles I know about, but it's in czech, so I suppose you're not interested :)

Comment: Please post the Czech link, I would be interested!

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, the StackOverflow didn't alert me about your reply. Anyway, here's the series: http://zdrojak.root.cz/serialy/doctrine-2/

Comment: -1 For claiming that there is no need for any other resources than the official documentation.